# HTTP request denied ( 3xx 4xx responses )

Tags: c, send, http-1.1, server-response

i ve decieded to ask this question after reading HTTP 1.1 usage. i don't get why i cannot access even www.google.com . its giving 3xx to 4xx(nearly all errors) error everytime. i ve tried every combination of these GET HOST CONNECT thingys in HTTP/1.1 but still not able to understand it. why my connections rejected/throwed/assumed as unsafe ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define TRUE        1
#define FALSE       0

#define INT_MAX_VAL 100000000
#define MILL        1000000

#define DEF_PORT    "80"

typedef enum compOpts
{
    higher,
    lower,
    hEqual,
    lEqual,
    equal,
    nEqual
} compOpts_t;

void checkErr(char *title ,int status ,int trueVal ,compOpts_t compType ,char* (*errFunc)(int errCode));

int main()
{
    int status,
        servSockFD,
        byteCount = 0 ;
    struct addrinfo hints ,*servinfo;
    struct sockaddr_in *servSock;
    char *ip4,
         *message = "GET www.google.com HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n",
         *htmlCode;

    /**initialization*/

    memset(&hints ,0 ,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    ip4 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    htmlCode = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*INT_MAX_VAL);

    /**getting server info's*/
    status = getaddrinfo("www.google.com" ,DEF_PORT ,&hints ,&servinfo);
    checkErr("serv info" ,status ,0 ,equal ,gai_strerror);

    /**Checking ipAddress*/
    servSock = (struct sockaddr_in *)servinfo->ai_addr;

    status = inet_ntop(AF_INET ,&servSock->sin_addr ,ip4,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    checkErr("ntop" ,status ,0 ,nEqual ,gai_strerror);

    printf("IPv4 : %s\n",ip4);

    /**creating socket*/
    servSockFD = socket(servinfo->ai_family ,servinfo->ai_socktype ,servinfo->ai_protocol);
    if (servSockFD == -1)
    {
        status = errno;
        checkErr("socket creation" ,status ,status ,nEqual ,strerror);
    }

    /**connecting through socket*/
    status = connect(servSockFD ,servSock ,servinfo->ai_addrlen);
    if(status == -1)
    {
        status = errno;
        checkErr("connection" ,status ,status ,nEqual ,strerror);
    }

    /**sending through socket*/
    do{
    byteCount = send(servSockFD ,message ,strlen(message) ,0);
    if(byteCount==-1)
    {
        status = errno;
        checkErr("send" ,status ,status ,nEqual ,strerror);
        break;
    }
    }while(byteCount!=strlen(message));

    /**recieving html code from socket*/
    byteCount = recv(servSockFD ,htmlCode ,INT_MAX_VAL ,0);
    if(byteCount == -1)
    {
        status = errno;
        checkErr("recv" ,status ,status ,nEqual ,strerror);
    }

    printf("%s",htmlCode);

    free(ip4);
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    return 0;
}

void checkErr(char *title ,int status ,int trueVal ,compOpts_t compType ,char* (*errFunc)(int errCode))
{
    int res=TRUE;

    switch (compType)
    {
    case hEqual:
        if(status != trueVal)
            res =FALSE;
    case higher:
        if(res == TRUE && status<trueVal)
            res=FALSE;
        break;
    case lEqual:
        if(status!=trueVal)
            res=FALSE;
    case lower:
        if(status>trueVal)
            res=FALSE;
        break;
    case equal:
        if(status!=trueVal)
            res=FALSE;
        break;
    case nEqual:
        if(status==trueVal)
            res=FALSE;
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error : Unknown comparision type.\n");
        break;
    }

    if(res==TRUE)
        printf("%s : succeeded.\n" ,title);
    else
        printf("%s : failed.\nError Message : %s\n" ,title,errFunc(status));
}
```

actually i want to get html code of any site using HTTP/1.1 .Guide me , where is wrong thing , what should i do ? i ve stuck at this code for 6 hours :S

NOTE: I will add if i can find its answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the spec.

The first line of the request payload should contain either an absolute URI or a path; not a hostname.
The domain name goes in the `Host:` header.

For more information, see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1).

Comment: i ve seen this usage at [here](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-latest.html) & i ve tried every combination of them [here an ss](http://i.imgur.com/HMh0tB6.png) why im taking 302 redirection ? i just request the bare page of google & still got a redirection ?

Comment: You're getting redirected because that's what google wants, that's all. When you went to www.google.com and request "/", Google gives you a Set-Cookie, and a redirect. Don't bother trying to understand this, it's just the way they've decided to implement things. If you like, you can take the cookie and follow the redirect, and see what you get from that, but getting a 302 at least means that you successfully submitted a request.